# Webpack - no output file generated?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I have the following webpack config:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')


module.exports = {
   entry: {
      main: './scripts/app/main.js'
   },
  output: {
     path: path.resolve(__dirname, './scripts/app/bundle/'),
     publicPath: '/scripts/app/bundle/',
     filename: '[name].js'
  },
  ...
```

When i run the command `npm run dev` it shows that main.js has been emitted

When I browse to `/scripts/app/bundle/main.js` sure enough the file is loaded in the browser

But when i look inthe physical path there is no file - seems like its only in memory

This is what I have in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot",
  "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules"
 },
```

How do I generate a physical file.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`webpack-dev-server` does not generate files on disk -- only on memory. However you do have some options:

- **Option 1:** Stop the dev server and instead run the command `webpack --watch`, which will use `webpack` to build your app and produce output to the disk. The downside is you won't have hot reloading.
- **Option 2:** Append `/webpack-dev-server` to the URL where you are running the server. So, if your server is running on `localhost:3000`, you can view files by going to the URL `http://localhost:3000/webpack-dev-server.` The files will still be served from memory, but you will be able to see them through this URL.
- **Option 3:** See **[this plugin](https://github.com/gajus/write-file-webpack-plugin)**. It will force `webpack-dev-server` to write files to disk.

Comment: Update: there is not a `writeToDisk` [option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverwritetodisk-)

Comment: @ChristianMurschall there is a `writeToDisk` option, but was moved into `devMiddleware` https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverdevmiddleware

Answer (score 0):

`webpack-dev-server` supports writing output to disk, use `writeToDisk` option under `devMiddleware` option

References:

- https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverdevmiddleware
- https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/migration-v4.md